# Pandas Dateframe query between two dates using dictionary value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have Pandas dateframe which has two column; ID and dates.
Additionally, I have a dictionary with start and end date and I want to extract data from Pandas dataframe which is between dictionary values.

Below is my data.

1. Dataframe (df)

| ID | Dates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20010302 |
| 2 | 20091212 |
| 3 | 20020924 |

2. Dictioary
   date_dictionary = {'start_date':'20020101', 'end_date':'20101231'}

If I use,

```
extracted = df.query('20020101<=Dates<=20101231')
```

then it works.
But I wonder why the following code gave me an error; UndefinedVariableError: name 'start_date' is not defined.

```
start_date=int(date_dictionary['start_date'])
end_date=int(date_dictionary['end_date'])
extracted = df.query('start_date<=Dates<=end_date')
```

I imported 'date_dictionary' using `from date_dictionary import *`.

Please someone why it doesn't work. And is there any method using dictionary's value inside the query statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to variables in the expression by prefixing them with an ‘@’:

```
extracted = df.query("@start_date<=Dates<=@end_date")

   ID     Dates
1   2  20091212
2   3  20020924
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) of `query`